# Keyboard shortcut for ls command?

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

Is there a keyboard shortcut for the `ls` command besides the alias `l`? I mean something like: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> for `clear` command.
One advantage, IMO, is that will not get in history list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `bind` to create a new keybinding, for example:

```
bind '"\C-g":"ls\n"'
```

Now press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd> to invoke `ls`. However, `ls`
will still be saved in history. You can add it to
[HISTIGNORE](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html)
though.